# Callback do $.get não é chamado e não consigo depurar para descobrir o motivo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, apache-cordova, javascript-eventos

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile (com cordova) que necessita fazer um select no BD online, e com estes dados atualizar o BD do celular, porém me deparei com um problema, eu realizo o select no BD do celular depois realizo um

```
$.get(url, parametro, fuction(data){
});
```

para selecionar no Banco online o cadastro, e dentro realizo a verificação se os dados estão diferentes e caso esteja realizo o update, mas quando dou um Debug ele não entra dentro do meu `get` me disseram que isto acontece pq é uma função ASSINCRONA mas não sei como resolver isto.

Meu código:

```
    queryDB: function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ouvidoria11', [], app.querySuccess3, app.errorCB);
    },
querySuccess3: function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        var protocolo;
        var tblText = '';
        if (len < 1) {
            alert("Não existe nenhum cadastro!");
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (results.rows.item(i).protocolo == null) {
                    app.protocoloSolicitacao(results.rows.item(i).id, results.rows.item(i).assunto, results.rows.item(i).mensagem, results.rows.item(i).endereco, results.rows.item(i).anexo);
                }
                tblText += '<span onclick="app.guardaVariavel('+results.rows.item(i).protocolo+')"><table id="t01" class="table-bordered">';
                tblText += '<tr><th>Protocolo</th><td>' + results.rows.item(i).protocolo + '</td></tr>';
                tblText += '<tr><th>Assunto</th><td>' + results.rows.item(i).assunto + '</td></tr>';
                tblText += '<tr><th>Mensagem</th><td>' + results.rows.item(i).mensagem + '</td></tr>';
                tblText += '<tr><th>Endereco</th><td>' + results.rows.item(i).endereco + '</td></tr>';
                tblText += '<tr><th>Anexos</th><td>' + results.rows.item(i).anexo + ' </td></tr>';
                tblText += '<tr><th>Prazo</th><td>' + results.rows.item(i).prazo + '</td></tr>';
                tblText += '<tr><th>Status</th><td>' + results.rows.item(i).status + '</td></tr>';
                tblText += '<tr><th>Departamento</th><td>' + results.rows.item(i).nomeDepartamento + '</td></tr>';
                tblText += '</table></span>';
                document.getElementById("tabelaSolicitacao").innerHTML = 

tblText;
                    var protocolo = results.rows.item(i).protocolo;
                    var nomeDepartamento = results.rows.item(i).nomeDepartamento;
                    var prazo = results.rows.item(i).prazo;
                    var statusBD = results.rows.item(i).status;
                    app.atualizarTabela(prazo, statusBD, nomeDepartamento, protocolo);//Chama a função para atualizar os dados
                }
            }
        },
atualizarTabela: function(prazo, statusBD, nomeDepartamento, protocolo){    
        var serviceURL = "http://ouvidoria.azurewebsites.net/Solicitacao/SelectAtualizacao";
        var parametros = { id: protocolo }
        $.get(serviceURL, parametros, function (data) {
            alert("Teste Get");
            if (data[0].meuPrazo != prazo || data[0].status != statusBD || data[0].nomeDepartamento != nomeDepartamento) {
                db.transaction(update, null, null);
                function update(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('UPDATE ouvidoria11 set prazo = "' + prazo + '", status = "' + statusBD + '", nomeDepartamento = "' + nomeDepartamento + '" WHERE protocolo="' + protocolo + '"');
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Obs.: Como dito ele chega a chamar a função `atualizarTabela()` porem não entra no `$.get`, nem chega a exibir o `alert('');`, ele exibe o `alert()` depois que termina o `for` da função `querySucess3()` dai ele exibe o varias vezes, exatamente o numero de vezes que a função `atualizarTabela()` foi chamada no `for` da função principal `querySucess3()`

O `meuPrazo`  está retornando `of undefined` quando eu coloco para debugar console.log(data) ele retorna o seguinte:

```
Object
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseJSON: Array[1]
responseText: "[{"id":0,"assunto":null,"mensagem":null,"endereco":null,"anexo":null,"status":"Aguardando","meuPrazo":"Indefinido","nomeDepartamento":null,"id_departamento":2}]"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Quando dizes "eu realizo o select no BD do celular depois realizo um $.get" podes mostrar o código que faz isso?

Comment: Tem como colocar o código igual o @Sergio disse.

Comment: Pronto realizei as alterações no post, ficou claro deste jeito?

Comment: Você está chamando a função `atualizarTabela` dentro de um `for`?

Comment: Sim por que dai eu verifico cada cadastro com o banco externo

Comment: Acho que é bom ter código assíncrono. Vou dar uma resposta aqui mas podes dar um exmplo do que `results` têm? (Podes fazer `console.log(JSON.stringify(results));` dentro de querySucess3). E outra pergunta: a linha `document.getElementById("tabelaSolicitacao").innerHTML = tblText;`  funciona como esperas?

Comment: Amigo, tive o mesmo problema que você eu resolvi criando uma variável e cada passa que tivesse que fazer somava +1 na variável, no final suponhamos que tive-se 5 processos, eu fazia um if(varivel == 5){} quando erá sim eu fazia o restante quando não era eu esperava 1s, isto fiz com javascript e perguntava novamente. Realmente banco mobile é assíncrono.

Comment: Tenta passar o quarto parameto 'JSON'; `$.get(url, parametro, fuction(data){
}, 'JSON');`

Answer (score 0):

Passe o parametro **async: false** no ajax deve resolver, vou demonstrar um exemplo:

```
$.ajax({type:"GET", url:view, dataType:"json", data:data,async:false,              // FAZ UM AJAX SINCRONIZADO COM A FUNCAO
        success: function(json) { retorno = json; },                                    // RETORNO DO AJAX NO SUCCESS
        error: function(json) { retorno=json; },                                        // RETORNO DO AJAX NO ERROR
        beforeSend: function() { $('body').css('cursor','wait'); },                     // RETORNO DO AJAX NO ERROR
        complete: function(){ $('body').css('cursor','default'); }
    });
```

Tem uma pergunta desse tipo aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re

**EDIT:**
no seu código ai em cima ficaria assim para saber se esta chegando algum valor retornado:

```
$.ajax({type:"GET",url:serviceURL,data:parametros, async:false,
    complete: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: A opção `async: false` está em precesso de remoção. Irá demorar bastante tempo para o mesmo, mas é preferível evitar a utilização da mesma. https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning

Comment: @Oeslei também acho que código fonte deveria ter a lógica contruída em função de rodar após o recebimento do get, fica a dica ai

Comment: Esta dando um erro 'meuPrazo of undefined'

Comment: verifica se o array esta chegando com ele teste um console.log(data) no debug @ViniciusVAz

Comment: @SneepSNinjA eu coloquei no comentário o console.log que foi retornado

Comment: @ViniciusVAz Editei minha resposta, da uma olhada ai e diz o que vem do console.log(data) e não console.log(data[0].meuPrazo)

Comment: @SneepSNinjA o retorno é aquele que eu comentei, é o retorno de console.log(data) não o de console.log(data[0].meuPrazo)

Comment: @SneepSNinjA na linha `responseText: "[{"id":0,"assunto":null,"mensagem":null,"endereco":null,"anexo":null,"status":"Aguardando","meuPrazo":"Indefinido","nomeDepartamento":null,"id_departamento":2}]" esta retornando mas como faço para exibir este valores?`

Comment: ta vendo que o campo meuPrazo esta vindo indefinido, então o problema é lá no php, o caompo id_departamento esta igual a 2 você poderia chama-lo assim: data[0].id_departamento