# Valor de variável undefined js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, apache-cordova, jquery-mobile

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile com o cordova, na versão mobile existe um BD que fica verificando se existe alguma alteração no BD online, caso haja ele atualiza no celular segue abaixo o meu código:

```
var serviceURL = "http://projeto.websites.net/Verifica/Atualiza";
var parametros = { id: protocolo }
$.ajax({
        type: "GET", url: serviceURL, data: parametros, async: false,
        complete: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.prazo != meuprazo || data.status != meustatusBD || data.id_Departamento != meunomeDepartamento) {             
                db.transaction(select, errorCB, null);
                function select(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('UPDATE ouvidoria11 set prazo = "' + data.prazo + '", status = "' + data.status + '", nomeDepartamento = "' + data.id_Departamento + '" WHERE protocolo="' + protocolo + '"');
                }
                function errorCB() {
                    alert("ERROCB");
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Porém o valor que é retornado de data.prazo esta como `undefined`, coloquei um `console.log(data)` para verificar o que estava acontecendo e percebi que ele esta sim recebendo os valores:

```
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: 
function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseJSON: Array[1]
       0: Object
          anexo: null
          assunto: null
          endereco: null
          id: 0
          id_departamento: 2
          mensagem: null
          nomeDepartamento: null
          prazo: "Indefinido"
          status: "Aguardando"
       __proto__: Object
       length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
responseText: "[{"id":0,"assunto":null,"mensagem":null,"endereco":null,"anexo":null,"status":"Aguardando","prazo":"Indefinido","nomeDepartamento":null,"id_departamento":2}]"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

Está errado o jeito que estou tentando receber estes valores?

Comment: Não será que queres usar `success` em vez de `complete`?

Comment: Conseguiste resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Corrigindo:
receba este parâmetro dessa forma:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data.responseText));
```

Answer (score 1):

Vejo duas coisas que podes mudar.

Quando usas o `complete` [o jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) vai passar como primeiro argumento o objeto `jqXHR`. Nesse caso precisas ir buscar `data.responseText`. Se a callback usares `success` em vez de `complete` ele vai dar os dados que o ajax retorna no primeiro argumento da função.

No teu `console.log` vejo que os dados estão em JSON, então precisas também de fazer parse deles, ou especificares no ajax `dataType: 'json'`.

Sugiro usares assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: serviceURL,
    data: parametros,
    async: false, // isto não é nada bom!
    success: function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data); // ou juntares em cima: "dataType='json',"
        console.log(data);
        if (data.prazo != meuprazo || data.status != meustatusBD || data.id_Departamento != meunomeDepartamento) {             
            db.transaction(select, errorCB, null);
            function select(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('UPDATE ouvidoria11 set prazo = "' + data.prazo + '", status = "' + data.status + '", nomeDepartamento = "' + data.id_Departamento + '" WHERE protocolo="' + protocolo + '"');
            }
            function errorCB() {
                alert("ERROCB");
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Vejo ainda que tens `async: false`. Isso não é nada bom. Se explicares poque tens isso posso ajudar a mudar a lógica para não usares assim.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda mas esta dando um erro na linha data = JSON.parse(data); o erro é este 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o'

Comment: @ViniciusVAz ok, diz o que dá `console.log(typeof data);`? estás a usar success ou complete?

Comment: Estou utilizando success, ele teve um retorno de 'object'

Comment: @ViniciusVAz então ele já está a fazer parse do JSON. Podes tirar a linha `data = JSON.parse(data);` e já deve funcionar.

Comment: Agora funcionou apenas tive que colocar data[0].prazo, sobre o async: false, foi uma solução que me passaram aqui mesmo no stackoverflow caso esteja errado peço que me ajude a pergunta está aqui:(http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72252/d%C3%BAvidas-sobre-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-assincrona-javascript/72412?noredirect=1#comment149000_72412)

Comment: @ViniciusVAz se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite